# Booking system database design

Tags: database, database-design

I creating a database for booking system.

Lets consume the following:

Hotel has 20 rooms with the same design, photos, price

So i have an entity like this:

```
Room:

ID
Hotel_ID
Price 
Quantity
```

How should i perform booking ?

If i consider all the 20 rooms as differ objects, everything is simple:

```
Room:

RoomID
Status
Price
Quantity


Booking:

BookingID
UserID
RoomID
```

With the second one approuch administrator has to do much more job and also i have data duplication.

Also i am curios about how to this with the first one approuch.

Comment: What "duplication" and so what? Don't worry about things whose names you heard in rumours. PS Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a third table named 'room-type' or something similar and save there the price, photos, desing, etc. 
Then you can create a relation with this table and the room table (where you store 10 records with the ID of each room) so there's not duplicated data and finally make a relation between the room and the booking table.